# Proving that three non-aligned points determine a unique plane

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

I started to study the axioms of Euclidean Geometry and i wanted to prove by myself a theorem (using only the axioms and rules of Euclidean Geometry):

> For 3 non-aligned points passes a unique plane.

However, I don't know how to do it. Can you help me?

ps: I found the previous statement (which i called "theorem) called "corollary". To me theorems and corollaries seems the same thing. Am I wrong ?

Comment: The classical 5 axioms of Euclidean Geometry are about planar geometry. You want to prove something about space geometry. Can you indicate what are the axioms you are working with?

Comment: As for "theorems" vs "corollaries" ... Both are indeed "the same thing", in that they are statements that are *proven* (as opposed to *axioms* or *postulates*, which are *assumed*). A corollary is typically a statement that follows easily from some result that one has just proven; it's like an added bonus for the work that was done. The term "corollary" describes a relationship between results as they happen to be presented by a particular author. What one author calls a corollary, another might call simply a theorem, because that second author proved the result directly.

Comment: So the statement i writed in main post is not a theorem but an axiom ? The italian wikipedia page about Euclidean Geometry calls it corollary

Comment: @Koinos I take issue with the cited Italian Wikipedia article. The axioms do not mention the concept of a _plane_, so you can't really prove anything regarding a plane using the axioms.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is provable by the rules and principles of Euclidean geometry. In fact Euclid seems to prove it in *Elements, XI, 1* (his first theorem in the three books of solid geometry: "A part of a triangles does not lie in one plane and a part in a plane more elevated", i.e. in a different plane. If three non-aligned points determine a triangle, and *XI, 1* proves that every triangle is in one plane only, then it seems the theorem follows from Euclidean principles, or at least Euclid thought it did. The theorem seems so nearly self-evident that some have wondered whether the short *reductio* proof he offers is really doing any work.